# Need to filter 3 columns with row_number()

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

I have data in my database like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
shopid | shopname | keyword | date     | filename
---------------------------------------------------------------
1      | shop1    | A_key       |2020-04-24| A     
---------------------------------------------------------------
1      | shop1    | A_key       |2020-04-24| B
---------------------------------------------------------------
1      | shop1    | B_key       |2020-04-25| B     
---------------------------------------------------------------
1      | shop1    | B_key       |2020-04-25| C     
---------------------------------------------------------------
2      | shop2    | C_key       |2020-04-24| A     
---------------------------------------------------------------
2      | shop2    | C_key       |2020-04-24| B
---------------------------------------------------------------
3      | shop3    | D_key       |2020-04-24| A    
---------------------------------------------------------------
3      | shop3    | D_key       |2020-04-24| B    
---------------------------------------------------------------
3      | shop3    | E_key       |2020-04-24| A 
---------------------------------------------------------------
3      | shop3    | E_key       |2020-04-25| B
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

the result i want is lastest data from lastest filename

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
shopid | shopname | keyword | date     | filename
---------------------------------------------------------------
1      | shop1    | A_key       |2020-04-24| B
---------------------------------------------------------------
1      | shop1    | B_key       |2020-04-25| C     
---------------------------------------------------------------
2      | shop2    | C_key       |2020-04-24| B
---------------------------------------------------------------
3      | shop3    | D_key       |2020-04-24| B    
---------------------------------------------------------------
3      | shop3    | E_key       |2020-04-24| A 
---------------------------------------------------------------
3      | shop3    | E_key       |2020-04-25| B
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to know how to do this with sql
my sql was

```
select *,rank() over (partition by date,keyword order by filename desc) rank
from table
 order by date asc;
```

Comment: I don't understand why three rows are returned for shopid = 3.

Answer (score 0):

> the result i want is lastest data from lastest filename

I don't fully understand this.  The following returns the rows with the latest date for each shop:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by shopid order by date desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a row per shop/keyword/date and if there are more than one row that meets this, use the filename to decide which is latest (C later than B etc)

You could use an analytic for it:

```
SELECT 
  x.*
FROM 
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      row_number() over (partition by shopid,keyword,date order by filename desc) as rn
    FROM 
      table 
  ) x
WHERE 
  x.rn = 1
```

But I dare say you could probably also do it with standard grouping:

```
SELECT
  shopid, shopname, keyword, date, MAX(filename) as filename
FROM 
  table 
GROUP BY 
  shopid, shopname, keyword, date
```

This methoid fails if you want to start adding other detial columns in but as far as I can see from your Q, there aren't any